# Метод search(). Регулярное выражение с условием

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию, которой передаёться в качестве параметра переменная строчного типа. Функция, с помощью регулярного выражения должна проверять: начинается ли содержимое этой строки с цифры или нет. Результат работы функции должен быть выведен на экран консоли. Переменная для передачи в функцию: `forTesting`.

Мой код:

```
var forTesting = "8 пінгвінів і 9 карасів";
function firstPosition () 
var regular = (/\d/);
var result = forTesting.search (regular);
if (result == 0) { 
document. write ( "Рядок починається з Цифри"); 
}
else {
document. write ( "На початку рядки НІ цифри"); 
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Может ожидают `/^\d/` ?

Comment: В добавок к ответу @АлексейШиманский. Вообще чисто для проверки я бы рекомендовал использовать [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) вместо `search`: `/^\d/.test(str)`. И было бы хорошо перед проверкой с помощью `trim` избавиться у входящей строки от лишней пустоты

Answer (score 0):

```
let forTesting = '1 строка с цифрой в начале'; // ваша строка
let forTesting_2 = 'строка без цифры в начале'; // доп. строка для примера

function firstPosition(str) {
  return /^\d/g.test(str)
    ? console.log('Строка начинается с цифры')
    : console.log('Строка не начинается с цифры');
}

firstPosition(forTesting); // Строка начинается с цифры
firstPosition(forTesting_2); // Строка не начинается с цифры
```